# Accessing a html element created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to stop the alarm being shown when there is no text in the input. The element that I don't what to show when there is no input is created inside the JavaScript file and I cannot access it. And i i can't use the 'TodoItem' div in the html because that will hide all the alerts. so every time that the add button is pressed it will output an alert when there's no input . but I just can't do that with the div with the id of ‘TodoItem’ in the HTML because that will make all the alerts disappear. In the JavaScript you will see a portion of code that is the btn.addEventListener . . . It has the comment above it. But in that I am referring to the ‘todo_alarm_dev’ which is inside of the ‘TodoItem’ but that is created inside JavaScript when you press the add button.I have made todo_alarm_div global but btn.addEventListener.. still doesn't solve it.

"I've been stuck on this for ages any help would be much appreciated"

```js
let notesArray = [];
let event_handlers = [];

// Add event listener for Add Button
document
  .getElementById("button1")
  .addEventListener("click", add_element_to_array);

/**
 * Add todo event handler.
 * Calls display_array functions.
 */
function add_element_to_array() {
  let splits = document.getElementById("text1").value.split(",");

  // loop through each item splits and push it to notesArray
  for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    notesArray.push(splits[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
  display_array();
}

/**
 * Display todo list with alarm for each item.
 * DOM Example for 1 todo item:
 * <div>
 *  <div name="todo_desc_div">Todo: Make Pancake</div>
 *  <div name="todo_alarm_div" class= ""Alert alertContaner">
 *    <input id="alarmTime-0" type="datetime-local" />
 *    <button id="alarmButton-0" onClick="setAlarm(0)">Set Alarm</button>
 *    <div id="alarmOptions-0">
 *      <button id="snoozeButton-0" onClick="snooze(0)">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
 *      <button id="stopButton-0" onClick="stopAlarm(0)">Stop Alarm/button>
 *    </div>
 *  </div>
 * </div>
 */



 const todo_alarm_div = document.createElement('div')
    todo_alarm_div.classList.add("Alert", "alertContaner") // Made it global so I could access it.
//still does not work.
//And i can not use TodoItem because all the alerts with not be visible.

function display_array() {
  const todo_container = document.getElementById("TodoItem");
  const todo_item_div = document.createElement("div");
 
  // For each todo item create div with description and alarm.
  // Todo: Refactor - instead of everytime forming whole structure write the code to append new structure.

  for (let i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
     todo_desc_div = document.createElement("div");
    todo_desc_div.innerHTML = notesArray[i];

    const todo_alarm_div = document.createElement('div')
    todo_alarm_div.classList.add("Alert", "alertContaner");//classList.add is how you add a class name to a element you made with js.




    const alarm_input = document.createElement("input");
    alarm_input.setAttribute("id", `alarmTime-${i}`);
    alarm_input.setAttribute("type", "datetime-local");

    const alarm_button = document.createElement("button");
    alarm_button.setAttribute("id", `alarmButton-${i}`);
    alarm_button.innerHTML = "Set Alarm";
    const wrapperSetAlarm = setAlarm.bind(this, i);
    alarm_button.addEventListener("click", wrapperSetAlarm);






    event_handlers.push({
      todo_index: i,
      wrapperHandler: wrapperSetAlarm

    });

    const snooze_button = document.createElement("button");
    snooze_button.setAttribute("id", `snoozeButton-${i}`);
    snooze_button.innerHTML = "Snooze 5 minutes";
    snooze_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      snooze(i);

    });

  
    

    const stop_button = document.createElement("button");
    stop_button.setAttribute("id", `stopButton-${i}`);
    stop_button.innerHTML = "Stop Alarm";
    stop_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      stopAlarm(i);
    });

    const alarm_options_div = document.createElement("div");
    alarm_options_div.setAttribute("id", `alarmOptions-${i}`);
    alarm_options_div.appendChild(snooze_button);
    alarm_options_div.appendChild(stop_button);
    alarm_options_div.style.display = "none";

    todo_alarm_div.appendChild(alarm_input);
    todo_alarm_div.appendChild(alarm_button);
    todo_alarm_div.appendChild(alarm_options_div);

    todo_item_div.appendChild(todo_desc_div);
    todo_item_div.appendChild(todo_alarm_div);

   
  }

  todo_container.innerHTML = "";
  todo_container.appendChild(todo_item_div);

  
}

const todo_container = document.getElementById("TodoItem");

const btn = document.getElementById('button1')
const input = document.getElementById('text1')



//The code i wrote to stop the Alert from showing if no text was i the input.

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if (input.innerText === '') {
    todo_alarm_div.style = 'display: none'
}else{
  if(input.innerText !== ''){
    todo_alarm_div.style = 'display: block'
  }
}})

//^^^^^



// Alert - Alarm
// var alarmSound = new Audio();
// alarmSound.src = "alarm.mp3";
let alarmTimer = [];
//const output = document.querySelector('.Alert')



// On click of set alarm button
function setAlarm(i) {
  const ms = document.getElementById(`alarmTime-${i}`).valueAsNumber;
  const alarmBtn = document.getElementById(`alarmButton-${i}`);

  if (isNaN(ms)) {
  alert("Invalid Date");
    return;
  }




  const alarm = new Date(ms);
  const alarmTime = new Date(
    alarm.getUTCFullYear(),
    alarm.getUTCMonth(),
    alarm.getUTCDate(),
    alarm.getUTCHours(),
    alarm.getUTCMinutes(),
    alarm.getUTCSeconds()
  );

  const differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

  if (differenceInMs < 0) {
   alert("Specified time is already passed");
    return;
  }

  const todo_timer = alarmTimer.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);

  if (todo_timer) {
    todo_timer.timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
      initAlarm(i);
    }, differenceInMs);
  } else {
    alarmTimer.push({
      todo_index: i,
      todo_desc: notesArray[i],
      timer: window.setTimeout(function () {
        initAlarm(i);
      }, differenceInMs)
    });
  }

  const alarm_handler = event_handlers.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);
  alarmBtn.innerText = "Cancel Alarm";
  alarmBtn.removeEventListener("click", alarm_handler.wrapperHandler);

  const wrapperCancelAlarm = cancelAlarm.bind(this, i);
  alarmBtn.addEventListener("click", wrapperCancelAlarm);
  alarm_handler.wrapperHandler = wrapperCancelAlarm;
}

function initAlarm(i) {
  // alarmSound.play();
  const todo_timer = alarmTimer.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);
  console.log(`Ring ring ring!!! - Times up for ${todo_timer.todo_desc}`);
  document.getElementById(`alarmOptions-${i}`).style.display = "";
}

function cancelAlarm(i) {
  const todo_timer = alarmTimer.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);
  console.log("cancelAlarm: todo_timer = ", todo_timer);
  window.clearTimeout(todo_timer.timer);

  const alarmBtn = document.getElementById(`alarmButton-${i}`);
  alarmBtn.innerText = "Set Alarm";

  const alarm_handler = event_handlers.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);
  alarmBtn.removeEventListener("click", alarm_handler.wrapperHandler);

  const wrapperSetAlarm = setAlarm.bind(this, i);
  alarmBtn.addEventListener("click", wrapperSetAlarm);
  alarm_handler.wrapperHandler = wrapperSetAlarm;
}

function stopAlarm(i) {
  // alarmSound.pause();
  // alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById(`alarmOptions-${i}`).style.display = "none";
  cancelAlarm(i);
}

function snooze(i) {
  stopAlarm(i);
  const todo_timer = alarmTimer.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);

  todo_timer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    initAlarm(i);
  }, 5000); // 5 seconds for testing.



  const alarmBtn = document.getElementById(`alarmButton-${i}`);
  const alarm_handler = event_handlers.find((item) => item.todo_index === i);
  alarmBtn.innerText = "Cancel Alarm";
  alarmBtn.removeEventListener("click", alarm_handler.wrapperHandler);

  const wrapperCancelAlarm = cancelAlarm.bind(this, i);
  alarmBtn.addEventListener("click", wrapperCancelAlarm);
  alarm_handler.wrapperHandler = wrapperCancelAlarm;


  
}




//let alarmtime = document.querySelector('# alarmTime')
//let alarmButton = document.querySelector('# alarmButton')
//const input = document.querySelector('.input')
//const input2 = document.querySelector('.input2')
//let todoitem = document.querySelector('.alertContaner')
```

```css
/* body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
} */

html {
  background-color: rgba(0, 89, 255, 0.514);
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  top: -20px;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.Quest {
  font-family: "Cookie", cursive;
}

#text1 {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
}

.h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.input2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Baloo 2", cursive;
}

#button2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Baloo 2", cursive;
}

html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#Result {
  font-family: "Do Hyeon", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quest</title>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap");
    </style>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap");
    </style>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cookie&display=swap");
    </style>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap");
    </style>
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Do+Hyeon&display=swap");
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- START CODE HERE: DELETE LATER -->
    <h1 class='Quest'>Quest</h1>
    <center>
      <h1 class="h1">Enter</h1>
      <input placeholder="Text.." class='input' type="text" id="text1"></input>
      <input  class='input2' type="button"  id="button1" value="Add"></input>
      <div id="TodoItem"></div>
    </center>
    <!-- END HERE: DELETE LATER -->


  <script src="src/js.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="src/variable.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```